# Weird failing request

Tags: images, shortcode, block-editor

Below there is a simplified version of the concept I'm trying to make work.

In a post, I'm manually inserting this core Image block:

```
<!-- wp:image {"id":7} -->
<figure class="wp-block-image"><img src="[picsum]" alt="ASD" class="wp-image-7"/></figure>
<!-- /wp:image -->
```

As you see, there is shortcode for the src attribute of the image, so here is the shortcode callback.

```
add_shortcode( 'picsum', 'picsum_func' );
function picsum_func( $atts ) {
    return "https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300";
}
```

Simple, right?

When I open this post on the frontend it renders the image properly. Also, when I open the post on the editor, it renders no image for the image block, but the block is surely there.

What is weird, is that in my console log there is this error

`GET http://example.local/wp-admin/[picsum] 404 (Not Found)`, which I cannot debug because the stack trace is not helpful, at least not to me. This happens with both the latest WP and the editor that it carries and with the latest version from the GB repo.

Can you help me identify what the problem is and how can I prevent this? Where is this request coming from?

The stack trace is this:

```
Image (async)       
setValueForProperty @   react-dom.development.js:1368
setInitialDOMProperties @   react-dom.development.js:5954
setInitialProperties    @   react-dom.development.js:6149
finalizeInitialChildren @   react-dom.development.js:7622
completeWork    @   react-dom.development.js:19113
completeUnitOfWork  @   react-dom.development.js:22324
performUnitOfWork   @   react-dom.development.js:22300
workLoopSync    @   react-dom.development.js:22265
performSyncWorkOnRoot   @   react-dom.development.js:21891
(anonymous) @   react-dom.development.js:11224
unstable_runWithPriority    @   react.development.js:2685
runWithPriority$1   @   react-dom.development.js:11174
flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl  @   react-dom.development.js:11219
flushSyncCallbackQueue  @   react-dom.development.js:11207
scheduleUpdateOnFiber   @   react-dom.development.js:21334
dispatchAction  @   react-dom.development.js:15795
onStoreChange   @   index.js:201
onChange    @   index.js:217
(anonymous) @   index.js:175
dispatch    @   redux.js:297
(anonymous) @   index.js:24
(anonymous) @   promise-middleware.js:20
(anonymous) @   resolvers-cache-middleware.js:52
dispatch    @   redux.js:659
unhandledActionControl  @   runtime.js:49
(anonymous) @   create.js:47
next    @   create.js:46
(anonymous) @   create.js:38
any @   builtin.js:15
(anonymous) @   create.js:47
next    @   create.js:46
(anonymous) @   create.js:37
Promise.then (async)        
(anonymous) @   runtime.js:37
(anonymous) @   create.js:47
next    @   create.js:46
(anonymous) @   create.js:38
(anonymous) @   runtime.js:39
(anonymous) @   create.js:47
next    @   create.js:46
(anonymous) @   create.js:38
iterate @   create.js:51
runtime @   create.js:73
iterator    @   builtin.js:90
(anonymous) @   create.js:47
next    @   create.js:46
(anonymous) @   create.js:38
any @   builtin.js:15
(anonymous) @   create.js:47
next    @   create.js:46
unhandledActionControl  @   runtime.js:50
(anonymous) @   create.js:47
next    @   create.js:46
(anonymous) @   create.js:38
any @   builtin.js:15
(anonymous) @   create.js:47
next    @   create.js:46
unhandledActionControl  @   runtime.js:50
(anonymous) @   create.js:47
next    @   create.js:46
(anonymous) @   create.js:38
iterate @   create.js:51
runtime @   create.js:73
(anonymous) @   runtime.js:59
(anonymous) @   runtime.js:58
(anonymous) @   index.js:27
(anonymous) @   promise-middleware.js:20
(anonymous) @   resolvers-cache-middleware.js:52
(anonymous) @   index.js:298
(anonymous) @   index.js:72
commitHookEffectListMount   @   react-dom.development.js:19866
commitLifeCycles    @   react-dom.development.js:19922
commitLayoutEffects @   react-dom.development.js:22938
callCallback    @   react-dom.development.js:182
invokeGuardedCallbackDev    @   react-dom.development.js:231
invokeGuardedCallback   @   react-dom.development.js:286
commitRootImpl  @   react-dom.development.js:22676
unstable_runWithPriority    @   react.development.js:2685
runWithPriority$1   @   react-dom.development.js:11174
commitRoot  @   react-dom.development.js:22516
finishSyncRender    @   react-dom.development.js:21942
performSyncWorkOnRoot   @   react-dom.development.js:21928
(anonymous) @   react-dom.development.js:11224
unstable_runWithPriority    @   react.development.js:2685
runWithPriority$1   @   react-dom.development.js:11174
flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl  @   react-dom.development.js:11219
flushSyncCallbackQueue  @   react-dom.development.js:11207
scheduleUpdateOnFiber   @   react-dom.development.js:21334
dispatchAction  @   react-dom.development.js:15795
onStoreChange   @   index.js:201
onChange    @   index.js:217
(anonymous) @   index.js:175
dispatch    @   redux.js:297
(anonymous) @   index.js:24
(anonymous) @   promise-middleware.js:20
(anonymous) @   resolvers-cache-middleware.js:52
dispatch    @   redux.js:659
unhandledActionControl  @   runtime.js:49
(anonymous) @   create.js:47
next    @   create.js:46
(anonymous) @   create.js:38
Promise.then (async)        
(anonymous) @   runtime.js:37
(anonymous) @   create.js:47
next    @   create.js:46
(anonymous) @   create.js:38
Promise.then (async)        
(anonymous) @   runtime.js:37
(anonymous) @   create.js:47
next    @   create.js:46
(anonymous) @   create.js:38
any @   builtin.js:15
(anonymous) @   create.js:47
next    @   create.js:46
unhandledActionControl  @   runtime.js:50
(anonymous) @   create.js:47
next    @   create.js:46
(anonymous) @   create.js:38
(anonymous) @   runtime.js:39
(anonymous) @   create.js:47
next    @   create.js:46
(anonymous) @   create.js:38
(anonymous) @   runtime.js:39
(anonymous) @   create.js:47
next    @   create.js:46
(anonymous) @   create.js:38
any @   builtin.js:15
(anonymous) @   create.js:47
next    @   create.js:46
unhandledActionControl  @   runtime.js:50
(anonymous) @   create.js:47
next    @   create.js:46
(anonymous) @   create.js:38
any @   builtin.js:15
(anonymous) @   create.js:47
next    @   create.js:46
unhandledActionControl  @   runtime.js:50
(anonymous) @   create.js:47
next    @   create.js:46
(anonymous) @   create.js:38
any @   builtin.js:15
(anonymous) @   create.js:47
next    @   create.js:46
(anonymous) @   create.js:37
any @   builtin.js:15
(anonymous) @   create.js:47
next    @   create.js:46
unhandledActionControl  @   runtime.js:50
(anonymous) @   create.js:47
next    @   create.js:46
(anonymous) @   create.js:38
any @   builtin.js:15
(anonymous) @   create.js:47
next    @   create.js:46
(anonymous) @   create.js:37
Promise.then (async)        
(anonymous) @   runtime.js:37
(anonymous) @   create.js:47
next    @   create.js:46
(anonymous) @   create.js:38
iterate @   create.js:51
runtime @   create.js:73
iterator    @   builtin.js:90
(anonymous) @   create.js:47
next    @   create.js:46
(anonymous) @   create.js:38
(anonymous) @   runtime.js:39
(anonymous) @   create.js:47
next    @   create.js:46
(anonymous) @   create.js:38
iterate @   create.js:51
runtime @   create.js:73
iterator    @   builtin.js:90
(anonymous) @   create.js:47
next    @   create.js:46
(anonymous) @   create.js:38
iterate @   create.js:51
runtime @   create.js:73
(anonymous) @   runtime.js:59
(anonymous) @   runtime.js:58
(anonymous) @   index.js:27
(anonymous) @   promise-middleware.js:20
(anonymous) @   resolvers-cache-middleware.js:52
fulfillResolver @   index.js:445
(anonymous) @   index.js:404
setTimeout (async)      
fulfillSelector @   index.js:399
selectorResolver    @   index.js:416
(anonymous) @   editor.js:74
(anonymous) @   index.js:139
__experimentalMarkListeningStores   @   registry.js:99
(anonymous) @   registry.js:158
(anonymous) @   index.js:118
useSelect   @   index.js:138
Editor  @   editor.js:49
renderWithHooks @   react-dom.development.js:14938
mountIndeterminateComponent @   react-dom.development.js:17617
beginWork   @   react-dom.development.js:18731
beginWork$1 @   react-dom.development.js:23314
performUnitOfWork   @   react-dom.development.js:22292
workLoopSync    @   react-dom.development.js:22265
performSyncWorkOnRoot   @   react-dom.development.js:21891
scheduleUpdateOnFiber   @   react-dom.development.js:21323
updateContainer @   react-dom.development.js:24508
(anonymous) @   react-dom.development.js:24893
unbatchedUpdates    @   react-dom.development.js:22038
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer    @   react-dom.development.js:24892
render  @   react-dom.development.js:24975
initializeEditor    @   index.js:141
(anonymous) @   post.php?post=5&action=edit:3649
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can you help me identify what the problem is and how can I prevent this? Where is this request coming from?

The shortcode is only processed on the frontend. As far as the block editor is concerned the URL specified is `[picsum]` which is an unprocessed shortcode.

There is no simple fix to this, and making it work will require extensive and continuous modifications to the fundamentals of how the block editor works that will lead to problems. For example, you could filter the block and dynamically replace the attribute with an actual URL, but then the new URL would get saved not the shortcode. Additionally, each shortcode will need to be processed via an AJAX call and independently, so they would not interact with each other, breaking a lot of functionality based on shared variables. At any moment the core blocks behaviour may remove all of this, undoing all the work. Also what should happen if the user tries to edit the image, crop/rotate, or replace it? You can't crop a shortcode.

**Shortcodes in HTML attributes are not the solution you were hoping for and you have hit a dead end.**

In this specific example, it would be easier to create an attachment that has an image URL generated by filters so that it's the equivalent of the `picsum` shortcode, but this is a separate task and one that likely does not help you as you mention in the comments this is just a simplified example.

Fundamentally this will require either creating custom blocks or implementing alternatives using filters.

For example, if your goal is to dynamically populate the src for the image, you can use JS filters to add props and controls for choosing a data source, then replace core attributes with the dynamic values. You can the use the PHP block rendering filters to place the dynamic values in the `src` html attribute when the content is rendered.

For inline text, the rich-text format library API can be used to insert a shortcode while displaying the processed value to the user. This is very similar to how inline images work where an image block is inserted inline yet an inline image tag is what gets saved

Comment: As I've written above., this is a simplified version of the concept I'm developing. In my concept, the shortcode is transformed properly also on the backend and the block shows the image without a problem. It's just that when the editor loads, I have this annoying console error in my log. I'm wondering what is it that triggers this request so I can either prevent it from happening somehow or transform the shortcode before that so that there is an actual URL there. For the latter, I don't know how soon, during the page loading, I need to do this.

Comment: yes, that's to be expected, the shortcodes in HTML attributes of core blocks idea does not work and will never work with the core blocks, you will need to find a different solution, this is not the solution you were hoping for, and will never work as you wanted it to in the block editor. The canonical solution to this problem is to not do it in the first place, it is a dead end.

Comment: If for someone the stack trace makes more sense than it does to me and help me identify the point in the code where this request is triggered, if there is one, I will most probably be able to find a way to overcome this. Anyway, thank you for your comments.

Comment: Also, FYI, I followed this concept with shortcodes in HTML attributes etc. while building the feature described [here (Dynamic Sources for All Gutenberg Block Plugins)](https://toolset.com/2021/01/toolset-blocks-1-4-brings-dynamic-sources-and-inline-fields-to-popular-block-plugins/)and it worked really well. My only issues so far are with the core Image block and with the core Media and text block.

Comment: That's because they used custom richtext formats and custom blocks to insert shortcodes and process them using the respective APIs, which is very different to what you're trying to do at a fundamental level. With custom formats they could insert an entire block inline, and they can populate a field with anything they want in their custom blocks. Modifying HTML attributes in core blocks to insert shortcodes however is another thing entirely. Even if you did it, the result would be saved, not the shortcode

Comment: I built that feature and for the part that I'm referring to (Dynamic Sources for All Gutenberg Block Plugins) it's not done with custom formats. It's with specific shortcodes all over inside the blocks' save component output.

Comment: sure the save component is fine, but the edit component is not, this is a dead end, you can't insert shortcodes into core blocks attributes and have them processed in the resulting markup. It might work for props that are processed into plaintext or richtext controls as it doesn't need to be processed for those, but not other attributes such as image tags. This is the source of your stack trace, the unprocessed shortcode

Comment: Likewise the 404 not found error is because `[picsum]` isn't an absolute URL so it's interpreted as a relative URL which resolves to `http://example.local/wp-admin/[picsum]`

Comment: if you had shared that you were trying to insert images sourced from a user selected dynamic data value, I could have written an answer about adding an attribute to control the source to the core image block, then dynamically replacing the image src based on that new attribute in the editor and on the frontend using the block render filters, no shortcodes involved. Shortcodes are not the solution here, there are better ways to do it

Comment: For the implemented feature, the shortcode is getting transformed into a proper URL, in time for the editor to actually render the image in the editor. 

In the block attributes for the edit component of the core Image block, there is a proper image URL where it needs to be, so what you are saying about shortcodes in the edit component is not accurate.

Comment: For example, [here](https://imgur.com/a/EayKHyQ) is the image block using the image set as the featured image for the current post. See, it works properly both on the editor and on the frontend. The problem is the console error I talk about in the question description. So this shortcode is getting picked up before it is transformed into a proper URL and this is exactly what I'm looking for, to find that place and make sure it will be transformed when the execution reaches that point.

Comment: That is not what my tests show, to get that result you would need additional code that you have not shared

Comment: Of course, in order to get this result, there is way more code that you need, both server and client-side. But for my point that would be useless because I even get the error, I'm facing with much simpler code.
Can we please focus on the actual error?

Comment: You will need to share that code to be able to reproduce the results, I no longer believe it is possible to answer this question with the information provided as the issue is not reproducible currently, and that the error you're asking about is directly related to the approach taken (hence my answer)

Comment: Thank you for your time.